# Post request with scrapy on homepage with ajax

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy, infinite-scroll

I am trying to scrape the prices of various pharmacies on the site https://www.medizinfuchs.de for a specific drug (e.g., https://www.medizinfuchs.de/preisvergleich/aspirin-complex-beutel-20-st-bayer-vital-gmbh-pzn-4114918.html).

The page works with infinite scrolling that is called via a Load-more-button. Using the network analysis of the developer tools, I see that the page sends a post request to https://www.medizinfuchs.de/ajax_apotheken, if I click this button.
If I copy this post request as a cURL and then convert it with *curl2scrapy*, I get the following code:

```
from scrapy import Request

url = 'https://www.medizinfuchs.de/ajax_apotheken"'

request = Request(
    url=url,
    method='POST',
    dont_filter=True,
)

fetch(request)
```

The network analysis shows that the response to the post request is in HTML format (analogous to the homepage), but **all** pharmacies are listed there with their prices (not just barely ten pharmacies as on the homepage before I click the Load-more-button).

My somewhat embarrassing question - I'am still an absolute beginner - is now how I integrate this post request into my previous python code so that all pharmacies are scanned and I get the price information for all pharmacies. My previous python code is:

```
import scrapy

class MedizinfuchsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "medizinfuchs"
    start_urls = [
            'https://www.medizinfuchs.de/preisvergleich/aspirin-complex-beutel-20-st-bayer-vital-gmbh-pzn-4114918.html'
        ]
        
    def parse(self, response):
        for apotheke in response.css('div.apotheke'):
            yield {
                'name': apotheke.css('a.name::text').getall(),
                'single': apotheke.css('div.single::text').getall(),
                'shipping': apotheke.css('div.shipping::text').getall(),
            }
```

I would be super grateful for support :-).

Christian

Comment: there is a more straightforward way to do this using requests and beautifulSoup if you're interested

Comment: My preferred solution would be Scrapy, but of course I am very grateful for alternative suggestions that help me :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to suggestions using only requests and beautifulsoup, you can:

- use a `requests.Session()` to store cookies and perform a first call on the url `s.get(url)`. This will get the cookie `product_history` which is equal to the product id
- use `requests.post` to call the API you've spotted in the chrome dev tools, and also specify the `id` in the form data

The following example iterates a list of products and perform the flow described above :

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

products = [
    "https://www.medizinfuchs.de/preisvergleich/aspirin-complex-beutel-20-st-bayer-vital-gmbh-pzn-4114918.html",
    "https://www.medizinfuchs.de/preisvergleich/alcohol-pads-b.braun-100-st-b.-braun-melsungen-ag-pzn-629703.html"
]

results = []

for url in products:
    # get id
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(url)
    id = s.cookies.get_dict()["product_history"]

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    pzn = soup.find("li", {"class": "pzn"}).text[5:]
    print(f'pzn: {pzn}')

    # make the call
    r = requests.post("https://www.medizinfuchs.de/ajax_apotheken",
                      data={
                          "params[ppn]": id,
                          "params[entry_order]": "single_asc",
                          "params[filter][rating]": "",
                          "params[filter][country]": 7,
                          "params[filter][favorit]": 0,
                          "params[filter][products_from][de]": 0,
                          "params[filter][products_from][at]": 0,
                          "params[filter][send]": 1,
                          "params[limit]": 300,
                          "params[merkzettel_sel]": "",
                          "params[merkzettel_reload]":  "",
                          "params[apo_id]":  ""
                      })
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    data = [
        {
            "name": t.find("a").text.strip(),
            "single": t.find("div", {"class": "single"}).text.strip(),
            "shipping": t.find("div", {"class": "shipping"}).text.strip().replace("\t", "").replace("\n", " "),
        }
        for t in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "apotheke"})
    ]
    for t in data:
        results.append({
            "pzn": pzn,
            **t
        })
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

repl.it: https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeMedicinFuchs

Note that in the solution above, I'm only using `requests.Session()` in order to get the `product_history` cookie. The session is not needed in subsequent calls. This way, I get directly the product id without having to use regex in the html/js. But maybe there is a better way to get the product id, we can't get it from the url since it only has part of the product id `4114918` instead of `1104114918` (if you don't want to harcode the `110` suffix part)

Comment: Thank you very much for the support and the code - it works great!
One more question: What is the best way to make the PZN for the individual URLs appear in the list so that the informations can be assigned to the respective medicines? 
The CSS selector for this is li.pzn, if I see it correctly. (Or possibly extract from the URL?).
And one more question (if that's OK): How can I export the results as a csv with the columns PZN, name, single, shipping?

Comment: @ChristianK. see updated post, you can parse with beautifulsoup for the first link and extract the pzn. convert the data into a pandas dataframe ans use to_csv

Comment: Great – works perfectly! And I learned a lot. Thank you very much :-).

Comment: Up to now everything has worked perfectly, but since a few days the scraping no longer works and I receive the following error message: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "…", line 23, in <module>
    id = s.cookies.get_dict()["product_history"]
KeyError: 'product_history'
In the network analysis of the developer tools, however, you can still see the item product_history with the corresponding value or the product ID under the response cookies in the post request for the Ajax pharmacies.
Do you have any idea where the error might be?
Many thanks
Christian